# How can I setup my local Nginx server so I can edit the files?

Tags: linux, security, nginx, http

I have my local development machine running Arch Linux, Nginx, PHP-FPM and MySQL.

In order for the websites I am working on to run the files need to be owned by the http user. The files are currently located in folders like this:

```
/srv/http/site1/
/srv/http/site2/
```

When I use the following chown command on the http folder the sites work fine, but I cannot edit the files with my user:

```
chown -R http.users /srv/http
```

When I do this the sites do not work, but I can edit the files:

```
chown -R shane.http /srv/http
```

How can I make it so that my user can edit the files, and the web server can run them at the same time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively setfacl the folder to give you write etc. while still have http own the tree. Acl should be supported in arch linux. Man getfacl and man setfacl for details.

Comment: That did it: setfacl -m group:users:rw- -R http/

Comment: Thanks a million, can't believe the time I wasted on that.